# redirect plumber api to https

Tags: r, apache, rest, plumber

i have an ubuntu server running a plumber API, which provides a REST interface at http://myserver.com:8080/somecommand. I used systemd to host this (see https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html#systemd). I need, however, that this communication is done via https.

I managed to issue myself a certificate and https://myserver.com now gives me the apache standard landing page. i have no idea though, how to put plumber behind that. I tried to run the plumber api on port 443, but the connection was refused. I also tried to redirect traffic in the apache configuration, but i only managed to route https://myserver.com/somecommand to http://myserver.com:8080/somecommand.

Any hints would be appreciated,
Felix

Comment: I saw in the plumber documentation how they setup nginx (a web server similar to Apache httpd) as a proxy.  It listens on 443 and proxies the connections to the plumber on port 8080.  You could do that.

Comment: ah, thanks for the hint. i managed to setup a reverse proxy in apache which redirects the traffic to port 443 (I found some advice here: http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/redirect-from-http-to-https-and-viceversa-with-apache-proxypass/)